# How to reuse a method from a helper inside of a lib module in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have `a method` in my `ApplicationHelper`:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def a
    do something
  end
end
```

and I have a module in my lib folder:

```
module MyModule
  def do_another_thing
   # How can I use the method a here?
   # I know that I can include the `ApplicationHelper` here, but I don't want to pollute my module with unrelated functions
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark that `a` method as [`module_function`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/module_function) like so:

```rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def a
    do something
  end
  module_function :a
end
```

and then use it like `ApplicationHelper.a`